# Logstash filter out multiple string

Tags: filter, logstash, elk

I have a log that i want to filter out and drop messages that do not contain two strings

It works well when i use one string with the filter

```
if ([message] !~ "Low Volts ") {
drop{}
}
```

I am trying to drop lines that do not  contain either of two strings "Low Volts" and 'Charge". I am trying this;

```
if ([message] !~ "Low Volts " or [message] !~ "Charge Fail")  {
drop{}
}
```

the above does not work

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That conditional says if the message does not contain "Low Volts" or if it does not contain "Charge Fail". Thus it is only true if [message] contains both. Try

```
if ([message] !~ "Low Volts " and [message] !~ "Charge Fail")  {
```

That will be true only if [message] contains neither.